# How to access previous conversation details in Dialogflow fallback intent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

What would be the best way of accessing the previous conversation details when Dialogflow maps the input to a fallback intent?

We'd like to steer the user back into the right direction by re-prompting the last suggestion chips that were given.

The way we do it now is by manually saving the last suggestions and manually resetting them if the conversation is progressing to new intent. Not optimal and error prone.

It would be good if all fallback intents contained the "last intent/response" information.

I also can't find the `isFallback` properety on the [DialogflowConversation](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.dialogflowconversation.html) object in the AoG SDK. So we're not able to reliably implement logic in the `middleware` handler. The [`isFallback` property](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/Intent) would be very useful to have access to on the conversation object in intent handler functions.

Any best practices for reliably setting and resetting a memory of last conversation for usage in case of fallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save all your current intent response details in a new output context. Fetch that previous intent response from the previous intent output context and the use that data to create a new response for the fallback intent.

Comment: Additionally, you can access the isFallback property in  `conv.body.queryResult.intent.isFallback`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas Satish, the output context pattern is similar to how we're solving it now. We still need to clear or over-write it whenever the conversation successfully moves forward. So we're using middleware to check if we should keep remembering the suggestions.

Comment: @Tlaquetzal thanks for the thoughts, the `isFallback` property is adressed in the original question. It's not accessible on the `DialogflowConversation` object when using the SDK, as mentioned.

Comment: @DennisAlund I meant with my response that `isFallback` is accesible from the DialogflowConversation object. I have tried it myself with the code I provided. I tried it with the fallback intent as well: `app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', (conv) => {conv.close(conv.body.queryResult.intent.isFallback ? 'detected!' : 'not detected');});`. You can see how this is possible following this route in the documentation DialogflowConversion -> body -> queryResult -> intent -> isFallback

Comment: I totally missed that! Thanks for pointing that out. If you want to formulate it as an answer post then I'll accept it.

Comment: @DennisAlund thanks, I think that this answer is a good answer, maybe @SatishPandey can add the additional information regarding the `isFallback` property

Comment: @DennisAlund Which conversational service are you using? According to https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs, Dialogflow and Actions-on-Google are available.

Comment: I'm using that aog SDK. I was just mistaken about whether you could find the `isFallback` property in the payload. I found it in the documentation, as pointed out by @Tlaquetzal (https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/dialogflow_api_v2.googleclouddialogflowv2intent.html#isfallback). Thank you 

Answer (score -1):

how about if you use `conv.action` or `conv.intent` to check for your fallback intent? You can create a middleware function that stores all the information you need from each conversation in `user.data` if it is not a fallback intent and use that in your fallback intent handler.

Comment: Could you explain more about how you can tell whether an intent is a fallback intent? In my search I couldn't find any information provided to neither the [intent handler function](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/actionssdk.actionssdkintenthandler.html) or [middleware function](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/actionssdk.actionssdkmiddleware.html) that contain that information.

Comment: the conv.intent will have a value of 'Default Fallback Intent' and conv.action will be 'input.unknown'

Comment: That's an assumption that you are naming your intent to "Default Fallback Intent". We already have a rule that all fallback intents must contain the word "fallback" so that we can string match them. But if you look in the request payload you can see that there is a property called `isFallback` that I am trying to understand where its equivalent is in the SDK

Comment: are you using API V2? I can't see isFallback in the V2 payload

Comment: Yes, it's part of the API payload. 
https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/dialogflow_api_v2.googleclouddialogflowv2intent.html#isfallback